# Fault tolerance in Copy Activity by skipping incompatible rows

Tags: azure-functions, azure-data-factory, azure-sdk-.net

I use Azure Fucntion with Azure SDK and Azure Data Factory, **is there any way to get value of skippedRowCount** of Activity Window when applying "log the incompatible rows" in Copy Activity (Source: Blob Storage, Sink: SQL Data Warehouse)?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you looked at what the PowerShell cmdlets for querying what the activity run returns?

Comment: Have you already looked at [Monitor skipped rows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-fault-tolerance#monitor-skipped-rows)? If you are using a blob trigger, did you check your blob for log file?

Comment: Customer 's requirements: using use azure data factory to import csv file in blob storage to SQL data warehouse. And archive the processed file to other place in blob storage; one place for those files are imported successfully and one for fail files (the files have incompatible data - wrong format, wrong length). I use the strategy  "Fault tolerance and log the incompatible rows in Azure Blob storage" so I need get value of skippedRowCount of Activity Window to know this activity which has some incompatible rows.

Comment: From my research in Azure SDK,  there are no support to get this value. I already look for in PowerShell, there are also no ways to get one. Because I am newbie in Azure, I ask for sure I don't miss any solution.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation here : [Monitor skipped rows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-fault-tolerance#monitor-skipped-rows), looks like a log file is automatically generated when log incompatible rows is enabled at https://[your-blob-account].blob.core.windows.net/[path-if-configured]/[copy-activity-run-id]/[auto-generated-GUID].csv. You can set up a [blob trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob) on the generated log file. Here is a sample function.json

```
"disabled": false,
"bindings": [
    {
        "name": "myBlob",
        "type": "blobTrigger",
        "direction": "in",
        "path": "[path-if-configured]/[copy-activity-run-id]",
        "connection":"MyStorageAccountAppSetting"
    }
]
```

Note: you could also use [blob name patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob#trigger---blob-name-patterns) to specify path in the binding.

In the function code, you can easily access the contents of the log file to get the skippedRowCount